# php switch menu undefined variable

Tags: php, variables

The following code has been moved to a new server and is throwing this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: menu in * on line 128
Notice: Undefined variable: menu in * on line 160
Notice: Undefined variable: menu in * on line 170
```

Here is the code:

```
<a href="index.php?menu=profile">Profile</a>
<a href="index.php?menu=regisztracio">Regisztráció</a>
<a href="index.php?menu=kapcsolat">Kapcsolat</a>
<?php switch($menu)
{
    case "profile":
    {
        echo("profil");
    }
    case "regisztracio":
    {
        echo("regisztráció");
    }
    case "kapcsolat":
    {
        echo("kapcsolat");
    }
    default:
    {
        echo("Home page");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: where is come from $menu?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions and answers are supposed to be in English language, so there is a bigger chance of understanding what you want. Please translate your post!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your lang but the problrem is you are not using `$_GET['menu']` to retrieve the GET parameter.

```
$menu = $_GET['menu'];
switch($menu) {
....
}
```

Comment: The "$menu = $_GET['menu'];" it works, but when I look at the first page provides a new error until you click for menu.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: menu in * on line 126

Comment: finally it works $menu = @$_GET['menu'];switch($menu) thx all comments

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="index.php?menu=profile">Profile</a>

<a href="index.php?menu=regisztracio">Regisztráció</a>

<a href="index.php?menu=kapcsolat">Kapcsolat</a>
```

here "menu " is not a php variable. You should pass value as $menu to switch ( `$menu = $_GET['menu'];` ). Not "menu" to switch.

Answer (score 0):

`$menu` is undefined.

It is not set anywhere, e.g.

```
$menu  = "profile";
```